# How not to reload a swf onbject if a page is reloaded

Tags: javascript, wordpress, swfobject

I've created a wordpress theme for a fashion shop and the client now wants to have a song that plays in the background.

i found a neat [flash player](http://www.alsacreations.fr/dewplayer.html) and i am wondering if its possible not to reset when the user goes to a different page or if the user have stopped the song and changed the page etc.

Any thoughts or directions?

Answer (score 0):

> *i am wondering if its possible not to reset when the user goes to a
>   different page*

by that you mean when the user goes from yoursite.com/mainpage.htm to yoursite.com/theotherpage.htm right?

if so, cant you add a (permanent) iframe and have your player in it?